# glib How to enable g_debug output on Windows?

Tags: debugging, glib

can you explain me, how I can enable the debug output (g_debug calls) in a Windows environment? (specific 8.1)
I've set G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all, but don't get any output.
At least not in the console window and not in Windows Event viewer.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you set G_MESSAGES_DEBUG? Among the enviroment variables?

Comment: Yes. If I input "set" in the cmd window I see it is set. But in the meantime I know it is related to SDL. SDL redirects stdout/err on windows in files, because compiling with -mwindows there is no console. This also works with cout and cerr. But the g_log stuff is not in these files. The SDL redirect can be disabled with set SDL_STDIO_REDIRECT=0, but no change because of -mwindows there is no console and so no output, too. Would I recompile with -mconsole then there is g_log output in an always visible console window. I think I have to program some log handler for the g_log stuff.